# Flash player 10 XML and AS2 problem

Tags: xml, actionscript-2, flash, htmltext

I am having trouble with less than (<) symbol in the most recent version of flash player for an AS2 app. I have an XML which contains strings of html text that I am passing to a text field like the code below shows. But in the browser the text after `&lt;` disappears(even if it shows on machines player). Now I know that if I replace `&lt;` with `&LT;` it will work but this is not an option. Does anyone have a suggestion.

```
var internalXML:XML = new XML("<annotation><![CDATA[<P ALIGN='LEFT'><FONT LETTERSPACING='0' KERNING='0'>this is the visible text &lt; this text will dissapear</FONT><P>]]></annotation>");
    var internalXMLNode:XMLNode = internalXML.firstChild;
    internalXMLDisplay.htmlText = internalXMLNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: I've experience the very same bug today. Thought I was going crazy...
Same setup: Flash Player 10, AS2, loading external xml.

`&lt;` breaks up the remainder of the string.
`&LT;` (caps) works...

The odd behavior is limited to my workstation. It works fine on other machines (some with same hardware, OS and Flash Player version as mine, others not).

This is pointing straight at a Flash player bug, maybe a corrupt install... I'll try reinstalling.

Comment: I confirmed my hypothesis: Flash player 10.1 standalone from my Flash Builder 4 installation is the culprit.

Comment: I confirmed my hypothesis: Flash player 10.1 standalone is the culprit (I used the one from my Flash Builder 4 installation). I've compiled and played the file with Flash CS3 (using it's version of the standalone player) and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just copy & paste your code and everything worked pretty fine for me.
Are you sure that your 'internalXMLDisplay is a dynamic text and / or it accepts html (internalXMLDisplay.html = true;) ?

Comment: That stuff is all fine. And it does work when I ctrl-enter from flash. But when I publish to browser...it goes bust